# Reverse engineering visible color spectrum with night vision glasses

Tags: visible-light, vision

Here's the context from a discussion I was having with a friend. Let's say I have a picture on my phone. Would it be possible to watch this picture on my phone with night vision glasses who usually have polarized yellowish lenses and seeing the same original picture's color/lighting/saturation/brightness/...by editing the picture?

In other words, is it possible to ''counterbalance'' the night vision lenses by editing my picture? It would be kind of kind of reverse engineering?

Thanks

Comment: The question needs to be clarified.  Do you want to wear night vision glasses to look at an RGB image on your phone, but see the image as if you were not wearing the glasses?

Comment: Yes exactly, just like if you were looking at the original image with transparent glasses. If it is possible, I guess the image would need a lot of editing...

Comment: You can't get back information that has been thrown away. If the night vision equipment produces a monochrome image, then that image simply does not contain as much information as the original, full-color image. You can't get it back. There's no place to get it back _from_.

Comment: I don't think that there is any reason, in principle, why somebody could not make full-color night vision equipment. But it would be expensive, and it might not be as sensitive as existing night-vision systems. If it doesn't exist, then that's probably because there is no market for it.

Comment: How is this different from [the question you asked a day ago](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505895/recreating-visible-color-spectrum-with-night-vision-glasses)?

Comment: There are AI approaches to restoring color to monochrome images.  The result is a plausible, but not accurate.  What the AI recognizes as grass by texture gets colored green, etc.